# How to Deploy app using MAKE system on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, makefile, jenkins-pipeline

I want deploy a app using "make" on Jenkins pipeline. here is my pipeline snippet

```
stage ('Stack: Deploy'){
    agent {label "Dev"}
    steps{
      script {

            sh """

            make sam-package-from-sar sam-deploy

            """

      }
    }
  }
```

but i am getting below error

```
+ make sam-package-from-sar sam-deploy
the input device is not a TTY
make: *** [sam-sar-package] Error 1
```

Can any one here?

Comment: The `jenkins` service account does not have a tty, so you probably need to modify the `make` target to not require one.

Comment: Maybe your make target tries to ask for something?